# Automatically append database entries in Access

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, vba

I want to create a database of products where each product can have multiple colours. I wanted to know if it's possible to create a form which allows the user to enter the `Product Name`, `Colour One`, `Colour Two`, and `Colour Three`, but only add the record if that exact product doesn't exist already (perhaps an "add sale" button?). If it does already exist, then it would need to increment a particular field in the table `UnitsSold`.
(When the first record is created the field `UnitsSold` would be 1).

Essentially this is to record sales of custom products which can have different color combinations. I tried to make this by myself, but whenever I added a product with the same details, it just added another individual record (defying the point of the DB).

The only reason I want this functionality is so the user doesn't have to search through what will eventually become an extremely long list of convoluted records just to increment the `UnitsSold` field by 1 whenever they make a sale!

Comment: I'm sure you can build a macro that automates the lookup process.  You can count the number of rows that match your criteria (product + colour combos) and then if your count is zero you move on to the next step and do the insert, otherwise just stop.  My Access macros are a little rusty, but if you can't do it easily with a macro then you could do it for sure with a macro that calls a module function.

Comment: If you tell what version of access are you working on I might be able to help you. The whole idea is to order colors by it's id (name whatever) before inserting new row so that you won't get combinations of colurs ie (red blue green, green red blue, blue red green). Then if such a record exist you increment UnitsSold in other case just insert new row.

Comment: @Remou You are right, sorry. I was fixing other parts and just figured I'd change the rest, while not paying attention to your own answer below. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use instr, I reckon:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table As t " _
  & "WHERE Instr(t.Colour1 & "," & t.Colour2 & "," t.Colour3," & Me.Colour1 & ") > 0 " _
  & "AND Instr(t.Colour1 & "," & t.Colour2 & "," t.Colour3," & Me.Colour2 & ") > 0 " _
  & "AND Instr(t.Colour1 & "," & t.Colour2 & "," t.Colour3," & Me.Colour3 & ") > 0 "
```

However, I do not think your products can have an infinite number of colours, so you may wish to store a list of possible colours with RGB or such like that will allow the colour order to be determined.